# How to change fill color for inserted picture (icon) in Excel 2016 with VBA

Tags: excel, office365, excel-2016, vba

Trying to add an 'Icon' (the one under the 'Insert' tab - not the conditional formatting ones) and change the fill color. Using the macro recorder results in the following code:

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert( _
        "https://hubblecontent.osi.office.net/ContentSVC/Content/Download?provider=MicrosoftIcon&fileName=Document.svg" _
    ).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1 'this line throws the error
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With

End Sub
```

Which was expected as it's the same code used to change the fill color of a 'Shape'. The problem is that the code doesn't actually work. It throws a run-time error `The specified value is out of range`.

While trying to figure it out I noticed when right clicking on the inserted 'Icon' that the 'Fill' option is disabled, which is obviously not the case when inserting manually. I suspect it has something to do with the 'Pictures' object as opposed to 'Shapes' and/or the need to pull the image info from the interwebs, but I'm no expert. That's why I'm here.

What I want to know is if this is doable through VBA or if I should just take a different route?

Comment: No error in Excel 2013 but I don't get the image with 'This image cannot currently be displayed' in the worksheet - but the color changes.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie - Just discovered this article - [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Excel-2016-for-Windows-5fdb9208-ff33-45b6-9e08-1f5cdb3a6c73) - which suggests the icons I'm referring to are only available to Office 365 subscribers. And idk if my post was clear enough but the code works just fine with shapes.. just not with these new icons.

Comment: I added office365 as a tag - guess you will need someone with that package to help you diagnose. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize this answers an old question. I ran into the same issue and obviously the recorded macro was not much of help, so I had to do some tinkering. This works for me...

```
Sub Macro1()

    Const path As String _
    = "https://hubblecontent.osi.office.net/ContentSVC/Content/Download?provider=MicrosoftIcon&fileName=Document.svg"

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = ActiveSheet
    Dim insertedIcon As Shape
    Set insertedIcon = sheet.Shapes.AddPicture(path, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, -1, -1)

    With insertedIcon.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This is the only place online that I have found a solution that worked for this frustrating issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Change_Hand_to_Yellow()
Dim shp1 As Shape
Set shp1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Graphic 12")
With shp1
 .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
End With

End Sub
```